# Automatically create HP ALM objects

Tags: hp-alm

Is there any way to automate the creation of objects in HP ALM?  Specifically reports, release cycles, test set folders, and possibly test sets?

Currently, these involve a lot of time consuming manual work.  I would love to get some of it automated even if I still have to do some updates or it's clicking a button instead of just going on it's own.

I used ALM extensively, but only for Manual testing and the customization that exists was locked down.

Is there a way to create a button inside ALM that can do this?  Or is it simple with a script that I could write in UFT?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can check OTA API which allows you to write some simple automation scripts in VB or C# and then execute them.  
https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.55/api_refs/ota/webframe.html#topic4.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I looked at it, but it doesn't make much sense to me.  I'm new to scripting, though, so I'll investigate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, it can be done.  It is definitely NOT simple, but it can be done using mostly google and, to a lesser extent, the horrible OTA reference document that microfocus has provided.  I've done folders, test sets, and tests.  I even tied it to a button in ALM.

Next is Release cycles and reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a buttton in ALM and create workflows, its time consuming but it saves a ton of time, you need access to ALM cutomizations. We have buttons for release, cycles, Dashboard and test lab setup. If customization is locked down then you can use OTA API, other then the official reference, below is a good resource

https://github.com/sumeet-kushwah/ALM_OTA_Wrapper/tree/master/ALM_Wrapper

And below is the example of how to create a button in ALM

https://sumeetkushwah.com/2018/03/28/create-an-alm-workflow-for-moving-tests-from-plan-to-lab/